# What is the best way to push data from a rest api to an sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, api, phpmyadmin

I have 2 rest APIs the first one will return an id I can use to get more data from the second one. I want to push the result of the second api to my sql database in phpMyAdmin. what is the best way to do this? should I be writing a script in another programming language? I plan on pushing at least a hundred results.

Answer (score 1):

What language do you use to interact with your rest APIs?  Assuming it is a server-side language of some sort, such as PHP, then you would create a database connection in PHP (look up PDO, MySQLi), then you could write a MySQL command such as `INSERT INTO` to write your data to the MySQL Database.

PHPMyAdmin plays no role, except that it gives you web-based database management for doing things manually (such as view, write, modify, etc).

Comment: So I looked up the syntax and managed to write a php script that does this. Thanks for the suggestion.